Transpiling a circuit with Tket, taking topology into account
There is a simple circuit with one CNOT like the following:

Topology 0 → 1 (directed connection)
CNOT 1 → 0

Note that CNOT is placed opposite to the connection.
If this is transpiled correctly, it should look like the following circuit.

HH
CNOT 0 → 1
HH

What is the proper Tket transpilation pass(es) required to perform this transpilation?
I wrote the following code but did not get the desired result.
from pytket import Circuit
from pytket.circuit import Node
from pytket.architecture import Architecture
from pytket.placement import place_with_map
from pytket.passes import RoutingPass

nodes = [Node("node" + str(i), i) for i in range(2)]
arch = Architecture([(nodes[1], nodes[0])])

circuit = Circuit(2)
circuit.CX(0, 1)  # needs transpilation here

initial_mapping = {circuit.qubits[i]: nodes[i] for i in range(len(nodes))}
place_with_map(circuit, initial_mapping)

# transpile
RoutingPass(arch).apply(circuit)


DecomposeSwapsToCXs looks like it does the trick.
from pytket import Circuit
from pytket.circuit import Node
from pytket.architecture import Architecture
from pytket.placement import place_with_map
from pytket.passes import DecomposeSwapsToCXs
from pytket.circuit.display import render_circuit_jupyter

circuit = Circuit(2)
circuit.CX(0, 1)  # needs transpilation here
print("Original circuit:")
render_circuit_jupyter(circuit)

nodes = [Node("node" + str(i), i) for i in range(circuit.n_qubits)]
arch = Architecture([(nodes[1], nodes[0])])

initial_mapping = {circuit.qubits[i]: nodes[i] for i in range(circuit.n_qubits)}
place_with_map(circuit, initial_mapping)

DecomposeSwapsToCXs(arch, True).apply(circuit)
print("\nTranspiled circuit after applying DecomposeSwapsToCXs:")
render_circuit_jupyter(circuit)

